# How difficult to switch from manual testing to automation testing?

Tags: automated-testing, manual-testing

How difficult to switch from manual testing to automation testing

Comment: See https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/1703/transition-from-all-manual-testing-to-automated-testing?rq=1

Comment: See https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/3755/how-can-i-switch-from-manual-testing-to-writing-automation?rq=1

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I switch from manual testing to writing automation?](https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/3755/how-can-i-switch-from-manual-testing-to-writing-automation)

Comment: Voting to close as to broad. I do not think it is a duplicate, because the other questions are about how, not the complexity. But as the question is asked it is too broad, please ask questions about difficulties you foresee or have with the transition so we can give a better answer.

Answer (score 0):

It depends. Test automation is a different field, you will have learn new skills and have a [paradigm shift](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paradigm_shift) of how you look at building and testing software. So if you have a hard time adapting to a new world this might also be a challenge. For quick learners and progressive people this might be easy.

Also you need programming skills. If you find learning programming hard then the transition will be hard. There are record and playback tools, this might make it easier at first, but any test automation expert is a well skilled programmer.