# Open source deployment validation tool

Tags: automated-testing, tools, continuous-integration, open-source

Asked this on stackoverflow and earned myself the tumbleweed badge... Anyone here know of any?

I'm looking for an Open source tool to help with deployment validation for mainly web based applications on Windows machines (if it works with linux as well would be a huge bonus). Basically I'm looking for an automatic validation of deployment to run prior to smoke tests of the application itself. I'd like a data driven tool that would validate after deployments that everything is delivered (correct time stamps and versions), service is up and running, etc. We could definitely build something to do this, but I was surprised when I didn't find anything like it out there. Anyone know of any open source tools that will do this?

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7245195/open-source-deployment-validation-tool

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recently looked for the same thing and after not finding anything wrote my own implementation.  I took the approach outlined in this blog: http://www.testingwithkunal.com/automated-deployment-validation-using-net/ and from there I added the ability to test for some additional things outlined in my response to this question: [Deployment Testing](https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/1469/deployment-testing/1595#1595)

Comment: Sam- thanks for the input, I'm the one that upvoted your response to deployment testing :)  It was reviewing your response and this blog that made me begin searching for an open source option.

Answer (score 1):

No, there are no general purpose open source tools that could perform validation for you. 
Yes, there are a lot of small tools that could enable you to automate that validation.

The main question is what you need to validate. Do you have manual check list already?

Using any popular scripting languages: Perl, Python, Ruby, Jscript you could automate the

verification process and create a validation tool that exactly meats your requirements. You could use batch files and small utilities to validate the directory contents, file contents, and file attributes (diff, dir). You also could automatically verify the file signatures.

Use Jscript or VBScript to configure IIS and perform the operating system configuration validation. There are a lot of recipes all over the Web how to perform a specific verification, but there are no any general purpose tool that includes all of them.